# WebHook in Twilio API

Tags: twilio, webhooks, twilio-api, twilio-python

I can't find how to set up or change the Webhook through API.
Is it possible to change it, set it when I am buying a number, or select one Webhook URL for all numbers?

I tried to find this info in the documentation but there was helpful to me

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that with the following command from the CLI:

```
twilio phone-numbers:update <TWILIO_NUMBER> --voice-url https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io --sms-url https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io
```

or with Node

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.incomingPhoneNumbers('PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
  .update({voiceUrl: 'https://www.your-new-voice-url.com/example'})
  .then(incoming_phone_number => console.log(incoming_phone_number.friendlyName));
```

You can find other snippets in the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#update-an-incomingphonenumber-resource) (scroll to "Example 2 Update IncomingPhoneNumber to use a new Voice URL").

PS: If you want to reuse the same configuration for multiple phone numbers, you might want to see whether [TwiML Apps](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/applications) can help you too.

Comment: thanks, bro, you are the best)
It was really not so obvious to me, that it calls sms_url / voice_url.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) It would be great if you could go ahead and use the "checkmark" button to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to log into your Twilio console.

From the **Develop** tab, select **Phone Numbers**, then **Manage** > **Active Numbers**.

You can set the default Webhook (and back-up alternate Webhook) by clicking on the desired number and entering it under the respective Phone or (if available) SMS fields. **You will likely have to set the Webhook** (takes 2 seconds) **for each phone number purchased** as the default is the Twilio Demo URL (replies back with Hi or something)

**The nature of a Webhook should allow any change in functionality to be done externally (on your end) through your Webhook script's functionality and thus dynamically changing the Webhook URL through the API on a case-by-case basis is discouraged and frankly should not be necessary.** Someone may correct me if mistaken.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but I knew that.
I wanted to set the web hook through API.
Without using Twilio's console.

Comment: @nbo What purpose would that hold? Perhaps if you could provide one that can't easily be disavowed (proven to have little purpose) Twilio may institute such a function. Until then, if you can request/change a Webhook you can just as easily change it's internal functionality... it's a solution in search of a problem- as far as development goes. Simple class function. request (A) does function (A) request (B) does function (B). Create a private web interface that allows you to switch between any functionality you wish.